# how to initialize state with props without modifying props in vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, vuejs3

I initialize state in my vue 3 component as follows:

```
data() {
    return {
        new_listing: this.listing //which is a prop
    }
}
```

However when I bind it to an input for example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="title" v-model="new_listing.title" />
```

the expected result is for only `new_listing.title` to change, however the prop `listing` also seems to change. How do I make it so that only the state `new_listing.title` changes and not the prop `listing.title`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clone the object (make a new copy).

In javascript when assigning an object to a variable it doesn't create a new copy of that object. Instead it assigns it by referencing the original object.

Therefore from the code in your question, doing `{ new_listing: this.listing }` assigns a reference of the `this.listing` object to `new_listing`. Meaning that modifying `new_listing` would also modify `this.listing`:

To clone the object **in ES6+** you can do the following. The `...` is a [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). In this case it's a way to clone an object.

```js
data() {
    return {
        new_listing: {...this.listing} //which is a prop
    }
}
```

If you're **not using ES6** check out [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) to see how to clone an object.

**Note:** If the object contains objects (e.g. `{a: {b: "h"}}` then you will need to do [a deep clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript) (clone objects within the objects).